# Oracle EBS .ClassNotFoundException: oracle.apps.fnd.formsClient.FormsLauncher.class ERROR

Tags: java, forms, oracle, oracleapplications, oracle-application-server

I need help in configuring Java on my machine because, when I try loading Forms, the loader just goes in circles and gives this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.apps.fnd.formsClient.FormsLauncher.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run
    (Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried re-installing Firefox, older versions of Java Runtime Environments, disabling proxy.

What could I be missing? The application is working well on a other machines.

Comment: What version of apps are you running? Is this a clustered environment? Also what version of firefox are you running? Have you tried it with internet explorer?

Comment: am runnning in firefox 33, the oracle application is R12 . Yes i have tried running in internet Exploler but nothing seems to work when i try loading the forms

Comment: Try this : enable Java debugging window. Tell us whether that starts or not. If it does, what does it display ? Check **all** Java on the error machine (and on 1 that is working), spot any changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent around 100 hours finding a solution. Did not want to use Internet Explorer even though it also had issue of text being garbled (undefined) in labels. I had to use Oracle E Business Suite. So this worked best for me. 
There were so many issues. Some were related to SSL and TLS version on the website I was accessing. Then there were problems with the Java Version as well. I guess I found the solution.

I found a solution for this as follows:

1. Remove all Java versions. Install only between Java 1.6.24 Java 1.6.37 worked for me. All version latest e.g. 1.7.79 or 1.8.45 still had issues for me.
2. Download Chrome Version 34 or Firefox 30 to 35. Newer versions did not work for me, you can check. I guess it had something to do with SSL version 3 support and TLS support. Add Oracle EBS Pluin R12& R11i Enablement for Chrome if using Chrome. For fireFox no additional plugin is required.
3. Disable TLS in Internet options: 
   Internet Options> Advanced> Scroll down to Security Disable / Un check all Use TLS 1.0, Use TLS 1.1 and Use TLS 1.2.
4. Disable TLS in Java: 
   In newer Java Versions 1.8 Oracle has by default enable enable TLS 1.1 TLS 1.2. You have to disable them. 
   disable it. Go to Java control Panel> Goto Advanced Tab> Click General or Security Tree. > If you see TLs 1.1 or TLS 1.2 uncheck them.

Start your application. I hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by a client configuration issue.
There are a couple of recommendations here:

1. Use a supported browser, all the time.
2. If you are running JRE 7, please verify that your server has been configured properly to serve in JRE 7.
3. If you have SSL enabled, ensure that your client configuration is correct.
4. If you are over VPN, you will need to verify that your VPN is not dropping the connection.
5. If you are on Java 7, make sure that your server name has been added to the site list in the security settings.
6. Check the application.log and access_log for any mention of your clients connection.

If you have further problems I would recommend opening an Oracle SR for support as there could be many other things going on.

Comment: I solved the issue the error was caused by an active proxy in my java. i removed the proxy and the forms are all working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue the error was caused by an active proxy in my java. i removed the proxy and the forms are all working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

For me unchecking the TLS have not helped.
I resolved it by using Java jre_1.8.0_212 32 bit and changed the settings in Java Control panel made use the 32 bit system.
Hope this helps you